# multiple choice with at least one correct answer among the choices

Tags: vb.net

I'v been working on how to do MCQ in visual basic with at least one correct answer among the choices. i'v been advised from a very nice person to apply some changes and amend it however, I'm stuck and I need assistance.

the issue: when I click the button1 sometimes I can see there is no correct answer among the choice which leads me to click button1 again to skip the question. i'v been advised  from the nice person to connect each name with the answers and create  separate table then make some codes to connected with the answers...I apolgise for my understanding and the difficulties doing it.
for information in my example (Richard= IT , andy=commercial , simon= project , jim= English , chris= quality)

Please assist me for one point I really appreciated :

1. there must be a correct answer among the choices (even if its mean connecting the names in table) provide the codes please or amend my codes bellow.

Below is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CheckBox1.Visible = True
        CheckBox2.Visible = True
        CheckBox3.Visible = True
        CheckBox4.Visible = True

        Dim wlistq As String() = {"richard", "chris", "andy", "simon", "jim"}
        Label1.Text = wlistq(New Random().Next(0, wlistq.Length - 1))

        Dim wlista As String() = {"IT", "quality", "commercial", "project", "english"}
        Dim ra As New Random
        For i = 1 To 4
            Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Text = GetValue(wlista, ra, wlistq.Length - i)
        Next

    End Sub
    Private Function GetValue(myList As String(), ra As Random, n As Integer) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim tempStrng As String

        i = ra.Next(0, n - 1)
        tempStrng = myList(i)
        myList(i) = myList(n)
        Return tempStrng
    End Function

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

        CheckAnswer(sender)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        CheckAnswer(sender)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox3.CheckedChanged
        CheckAnswer(sender)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox4.CheckedChanged
        CheckAnswer(sender)
    End Sub

    Private Function CheckAnswer(chkBox As CheckBox) As Boolean
        If (Label1.Text = "richard" And chkBox.Text = "IT") Or (Label1.Text = "andy" And chkBox.Text = "commercial") Or (Label1.Text = "chris" And chkBox.Text = "quality") Then DisableCheckBoxes(chkBox)

    End Function

    Private Sub DisableCheckBoxes(chkBox As CheckBox)
        For i = 1 To 4
            If Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Name <> chkBox.Name Then Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Visible = False
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

thank you very much

Comment: The easiest modification for you would be, after generating the checkboxes, verify if the correct answer is among them; if not, choose one of them randomly and replace it with the correct answer.

Comment: in codes please

Comment: No I am not going to code it. I could just give you a tip after reading (not without difficulty) the code you provided. Maybe someone else is willing to, but basically I believe that what I did is within the spirit of this site: help coders, not code-for-me. All the best my friend :)

Comment: I appreciate what you did ... thank you.however,coding will help me better to solve it since I stuck with the above as you know I didn't raise the question if I know how to code it....anyway thank you I really appreciate your help :) but I still looking for more assistance.

Comment: The first thing to do is to edit your question and change the tag to VB.net instead of VBA. Well, I will do it for you, since this will be your best chance to get the help you need.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  The "questions" looks like male first names and the "answers" look like job descriptions or random words.  How are we supposed to know which one(s) are correct?

Comment: @Shildon - You need to change your `.Next(0, wlistq.Length - 1)` calls to `.Next(0, wlistq.Length)` as the second parameter is an exclusive maximum - otherwise you never will get the last item in your list.

Comment: Thank you guys so much... I put my equation in the question which is five guys and five departments ( Richard = it , Andy = commercial ....etc)... I mean in any question the word Richard appears there must be (IT) in the choices.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise that I don't have time right now for a full explanation, but if you ping me in the comments I'll do so later.

You could try something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _checkboxes As CheckBox() = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4, CheckBox5}
    Private _question As Question = New Question With
    {
        .Answer = "richard",
        .Choices = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
        {
            {"richard", "IT"},
            {"chris", "quality"},
            {"andy", "commercial"},
            {"simon", "project"},
            {"jim", "english"}
        }
    }
    Private _answer As Integer
    Private _shuffle As Integer()
    Private _random As New Random()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        _shuffle = _
            Enumerable _
                .Range(0, _question.Choices.Count) _
                .OrderBy(Function (x) _random.Next()) _
                .ToArray()

        _answer = _random.Next(0, _question.Choices.Count)

        Label1.Text = _question.Choices.ElementAt(_answer).Key

        For i = 0 To _question.Choices.Count
            _checkboxes(i).Visible = True
            _checkboxes(i).Text = _question.Choices.ElementAt(i).Value
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisableCheckBoxes(chkBox As CheckBox)
        For i = 1 To 4
            If _checkboxes(i).Name <> chkBox.Name Then _checkboxes(i).Visible = False
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Question
    Public Choices As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Answer As String
End Class
```

Comment: thank you enigmativity for what you have done really appreaciated... however, when I just start the mcq and click button1 it suddenly stopped and give me error message in this line (  _checkboxes(i).Visible = True...._checkboxes(i).Text ...) cant run it.

Comment: @Shildon - The code I posted isn't complete - you need to put in the rest of the code that this specifically doesn't replace.

Comment: @Shildon - You didn't give us an [mcve] to work with so it is hard to be able to write complete working code that you can just plonk in.

Comment: Please accept my apologies... as i thought it is a short task to do but unfortunately I was wrong... my apologies again.

Comment: @Shildon - Don't apologize - there's no need. The more you work on a good question the better (and easier) the answers will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable a boalean when a radiobox is checked.
Then use an If Statement to check

`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If boolean1 = True Then
....       'write your code for what happens if it is true.
Else
....       'If another one was checked instead.

End If
End Sub`

Comment: what im looking Tgamer is : in my case for example sometimes  label1 shows (simon) but I can not find any word related to him which is has to be (project) in all the checkboxes...that's my issue.... so in this case how to apply your statement ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what the names are and what they do. I only understood that your program does not detect the right answer when chekced. The thing is, Your program unfortunately looks complicated for no reason. Since I'm not a professional coder, your code makes no sense to me (And that's my fault, I know). My way makes it easier to read and understand, and besides, you don't have to do what Mr.Nice Person told you because remember: Any task can be accomplished in a different way.

Comment: It looks to me like a simple MCQ like an online test or something. I don't get the names part. A radiobox's text should be enough even without any string.

Comment: I apologize for making it sound difficult ...yes it is MCQ test. However, if you can see in my original codes in the original question it work very well. Only one tiny error missing which is sometimes no correct answers in the checkboxes which leads me to skip the question it self. it's ok that you are not professional coder neither do I. it's nice we help each other.

Comment: How about this:Tell me the question and options where it does not work, and I'll try to make a specific piece of code.

Comment: The choices must be in my case:  (Richard= IT , andy=commercial , simon= project , jim= English , chris= quality)........every time I see label 1= Simon  ... in one of the checkboxes there must be a choice " project" ......... sometimes I see label1= "Simon " but the choices are : a-quality b-commercial c-English d-IT ...no "project" which is all the choices are wrong.......so it does happen many times for each guy name ...no correct choice in the checkboxes .

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The problem is that because you don't want a pattern, your choices for each question are randomly selected from a list of total choices you have for all questions. In this way, in many cases you will not get a correct choice for the question at all.

What I think should work, try placing each question on a separate form.This will prevent answers of different questions to get mixed up. I don't know how you have you made your random choice selector,but you shouldn't do that. If you do, your error seems unavoidable to me. You can alter your code, (which I don't how, you should ask Mr.Nice Person) so that only the order of the answers is shuffled each time, not the answers themselves.

After a few attempts of translating your code, It seems my theory about your error is correct.

Comment: each separate quetion might work however, i'v been asked to put this in codes but I don't know how to do it?..... (as for the "at least one correct answer" issue, If I correctly understand you, you have to force one answer as the one corresponding to the chosen name, then you have to build up a table that gives you this correspondence and then 1) assume as the first answer the "corresponding" one 2) swap it with the one in the answers array last position 3) have your For i = 1 To 4 loop become a For i = 1 To 3 one.)

Comment: @Shildon - That's not what I meant. I told you, you change the order of their appearance, not to which question they appear. What the output is, the program only has 4 options to show, randomly ordered, for each question. Meaning, the choices will always be the same but orederd diffrently each time. And you can, use your code already, and regenerate it for each form. And for example, the 1st question will only have to choose between`Richard= IT , andy=commercial , simon= project , jim= English ` and the other question will have set another 4 names, etc. If helpful, mark this as solved please.